# Intermittent build errors with Jenkins and Maven

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

We have a problem that has been very persistent and I do not know how to continue tracking it down.

When builds are started in Jenkins, they sometimes fail for reasons unknown to me.

The error does not always show up, but the error message is consistent.
It always fails at the logging step seen below.

```
mvn --batch-mode -Dmaven.repo.local=/home/jenkins/jenkins/workspace/enial_amd64_javatools_PR-22-GHW7GOQFGYL5OCAMXQPD3JBXZFV6ALWUZZKH3IAEPERM6ZYB6SEA/.m2/repository clean install
---------------------------------------------------
constituent[0]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/commons-lang.jar
constituent[1]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/plexus-component-annotations.jar
constituent[2]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-builder-support-3.x.jar
constituent[3]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/eclipse-aether-api.jar
constituent[4]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/plexus-interpolation.jar
constituent[5]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar
constituent[6]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/plexus-utils.jar
constituent[7]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/cdi-api.jar
constituent[8]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-model-3.x.jar
constituent[9]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/slf4j-simple.jar
constituent[10]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.x.jar
constituent[11]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/aopalliance.jar
constituent[12]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/commons-io.jar
constituent[13]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-model-builder-3.x.jar
constituent[14]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/plexus-sec-dispatcher.jar
constituent[15]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/sisu-plexus.jar
constituent[16]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/jsoup.jar
constituent[17]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/eclipse-aether-transport-wagon.jar
constituent[18]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/eclipse-aether-spi.jar
constituent[19]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/eclipse-aether-connector-basic.jar
constituent[20]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/sisu-inject.jar
constituent[21]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/eclipse-aether-util.jar
constituent[22]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guava.jar
constituent[23]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-embedder-3.x.jar
constituent[24]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/commons-lang3.jar
constituent[25]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-compat-3.x.jar
constituent[26]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/wagon-http-shared.jar
constituent[27]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/wagon-http-shaded.jar
constituent[28]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/slf4j-api.jar
constituent[29]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/eclipse-aether-impl.jar
constituent[30]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/plexus-cipher.jar
constituent[31]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-core-3.x.jar
constituent[32]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.x.jar
constituent[33]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.x.jar
constituent[34]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/commons-cli.jar
constituent[35]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/wagon-provider-api.jar
constituent[36]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/javax.inject.jar
constituent[37]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-settings-3.x.jar
constituent[38]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.x.jar
constituent[39]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-artifact-3.x.jar
constituent[40]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/wagon-file.jar
constituent[41]: file:/usr/share/maven/conf/logging/
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Signature index 36620 in LocalVariableTable has bad constant type in class file com/google/inject/internal/cglib/core/$CodeEmitter
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2203)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3951)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3955)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4870)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4876)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:137)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:533)
    at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingProcessor$Processor$1.run(AbstractBindingProcessor.java:160)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.initializeBindings(ProcessedBindingData.java:44)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:123)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addPlexusInjector(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:481)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:206)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:545)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:281)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Signature index 36620 in LocalVariableTable has bad constant type in class file com/google/inject/internal/cglib/core/$CodeEmitter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:77)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:231)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClass(BytecodeGen.java:204)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:159)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:90)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:29)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:37)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:33)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:37)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3540)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2321)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2284)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2199)
    ... 28 more
```

These repositories contain many different projects with different target versions of Java. The failed builds are a mix of Java 7 and 8, we do not build to any other version than those. The failed builds are seemingly random and so are the number of builds that fail. Sometimes they all pass, sometimes 4-5 fail.

The exception thrown seems to come from Guava or Guice.

Googling this error returns tons of different reasons, most of them seem to be related to Java versions but I can't figure out why we are seeing this randomly.

Any tips or experiences with similar errors would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

This is the contents of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial

RUN apt-get --yes update && apt-get --yes install \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    curl \
    git \
    maven \
    openjdk-8-jdk-headless \

EXPOSE 22
```

In the pipeline script, we point to the resulting image as an agent.

We then mount the workspace from Jenkins using `docker run -v $WORKSPACE:WORKSPACE -w $WORKSPACE`. From here, the `mvn --batch-mode`, as seen above, is issued.

Comment: The output shows me that the Maven version you have installed there looks wrong...cause many file have wrong name or have tweaked the output ? Have you configured Apache Maven via Jenkins global tools configuration ?

Comment: @khmarbaise how can you tell from the output that the version is wrong? We have done no specific configuration, we pull Maven into a docker container that we use during the build and then discard the container.

Comment: All the files look weirds cause original downloaded maven contains the maven version in its name which means for example `maven-core-3.3.9.jar` instead of `maven-core-3.x.jar` ? Or `commons-cli-1.4.jar` instead of `commons-cli.jar` which means that is not the original Apache Maven....Furthermore based on the error message I would check which java version you are using (if you are inside a docker container)?...Can you give the references of the containers you are using ? So I could take a look ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have updated the original question with details about the Dockerfile. Isn't `sudo apt-get install maven` the original Apache distribution?

I will add steps to the builds to see if I can print out the version

I can see what you mean about the version, I searched for similar errors and some have output that looks like mine and others have a version visible.

Comment: Now I see that you are using the packaged part of Ubuntu...first I would try to run the maven build with a manually installed Maven instead of the one which is provided by Ubuntu to exclude that reason...

Comment: @khmarbaise I installed a clean virtual machine with Ubuntu 16.04 and ran `sudo apt-get install maven && mvn -v`. This is the result: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_151, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre